# Displaying images in a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

Using Python Tkinter, I was able to create a window in which I wanted to display a row of images to be used like buttons. To display the button images I used the following code. It is only a test script to try and learn how to, not the final script.

I want to create a row of images to be used as buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
#******************************************
#
#******************************************
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg="black")
root.geometry("1920x90+0+0")
root.overrideredirect(True)
#******************************************
#
#******************************************
miFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black",width=1920, height=90)
miFrame.pack()
#******************************************
#
#******************************************
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="/home/dave/python-programs/icons2/accessories.png")
b1 = tk.Button(miFrame, image=photo, border=0)
b1.place(relx=0, x=10, y=40, anchor='w')
#******************************************
#
#******************************************
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="/home/dave/python-programs/icons2/disk-apps.png")
b2 = tk.Button(miFrame, image=photo, border=0)
b2.place(relx=0, x=340, y=40, anchor='w')
#******************************************
#
#******************************************
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="/home/dave/python-programs/icons2/education.png")
b3 = tk.Button(miFrame, image=photo, border=0)
b3.place(relx=0, x=670, y=40, anchor='w')
#******************************************
#
#******************************************
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="/home/dave/python-programs/icons2/graphics.png")
b4 = tk.Button(miFrame, image=photo, border=0)
b4.place(relx=0, x=1000, y=40, anchor='w')
root.mainloop()
```

However when used it does create a row but each previous image only shows up as a blank area the image itself other than the last one does not display. Yet each image does display until the next one is added. i.e. b1 will display in the right place until I try to add b2 then the image of b1 disappears showing a blank space (of the right size) the image of b2  displays in its right place next to the now blank image of b1. This happens each time I add a image the previous images are blank blank the last one shows.
[image: image of results]
Can any one point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: It is because you have used same variable `photo` for the images.  Use different variables.

Comment: Many thanks everyone I have now manage to solve my problem by using a list of the button   and IMAGE_DIR  and the count using image[count] = tk.PhotoImage(file=IMAGE_DIR/'accessories.png' option. Sorry for the mistakes I made in my post and thanks for the edits. I don't know the correct way to use the forum at the moment. A head injury makes it difficult for me to do certain things so I am very grateful for the help given.    Take care Dave